# While loop in bash getting duplicate result

Tags: bash, unix

```
$ cat grades.dat
santosh 65 65 65 65
john 85 92 78 94 88
andrea 89 90 75 90 86
jasper 84 88 80 92 84
santosh 99 99 99 99 99
```

Scripts:-

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
filename="$1"
while read line
do
a=`grep -w "santosh" $1 | awk '{print$1}' |wc -l`
 echo "total is count of the file is  $a";

done <"$filename"
```

O/p

```
total is count of the file is  2
total is count of the file is  2
total is count of the file is  2
total is count of the file is  2
total is count of the file is  2
```

Real O/P should be 
total is count of the file is  2 like this right..please let me know,where i am missing in above scripts.

Comment: I am not sure what is the purpose of your script is.  It's doing exactly what it is asked to do.

Comment: thanks for your reply but my question is why we are getting 5 times of o/p ,but i need it one time mean o/p should --"total is count of the file is  2" like this.

Comment: $ cat while.sh
#!/usr/bin/bash
filename="$1"
while read line
do
a=`grep -c "santosh" $1 | awk '{print$1}'`
break
 echo "total is count of the file is  $a";
---Added the break and now it is working thank you...

Comment: The clue that you don't need the `while` loop is that you never use `$line` anywhere.

Comment: then how can i work with file in bash in UNIX shell scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst others have shown you better ways to solve your problem, the answer to your question is in the following line:

```
a=`grep -w "santosh" $1 | awk '{print$1}' |wc -l`
```

You are storing names in the variable "line" through the while loop, but it is never used.  Instead your loop is always looking for "santosh" which does appear twice and because you run the same query for all 5 lines in the file being searched, you therefore get 5 lines of the exact same output.

You could alter your current script like so:

```
a=$(grep -w "$line" "$filename" | awk '{print$1}' | wc -l)
```

The above is not meant to be a solution as others have pointed out, but it does solve your issue.

Comment: Maybe you should go back and read what I wrote.  I am not suggesting this is the best method, but rather why the user was having trouble whilst using this process.